# How to prevent repeating code

Tags: c#

I am a beginner programmer and  feel like I am repeating code(`DownloadFiles()`) as in the below example:

```
var files = DownloadFiles();
var retryCount = 0;

while (files == null && retryCount < 3)
{
    retryCount++; 
    Console.WriteLine("Retrying {0} time", retryCount);
    files = DownloadFiles();       
}
```

My application is basically downloading files via a HttpWebrequest` and is supposed to retry the download 3 times if no files are retrieved.

I need your expert opinion here:

I am repeating code with `DownloadFiles()`

Could this snippet of code be written more efficiently?

This may seem trivial but I want to develop good programming practices.

Comment: Generally this sort of thing is probably fine. In this case you might want to look into a `do...while` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not repeating your code, you already encapsulated the Download logic in a method, and you are looping over this method.

Bad things would have been to inline the DownloadFiles method or to unroll the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `do ... while` as Ben Aaronson already suggested:

```
TypeOfFiles files;
var retryCount = 0;

do
{
    files = DownloadFiles();       

    if (retryCount > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Retrying {0} time", retryCount);
    }
}
while (files == null && retryCount++ < 3)
```

I moved the `retryCount++` to inside the `while` so your number doesn't get off (compared to do this inside the loop).

Comment: You cant use `var` without providing some context to the compile. OP's code doesn't print "Retrying" on first attempt. And, your code will only download 3 times whilst OP's code will do 4 times.

Comment: @Xiaoy312: I don't think it runs 3 times, since the `++` on `retryCount` is done AFTER evaluating the expression (as opposed to `++retryCount`).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is:

```
List<File> files;  // replace with whatever type files is
var retryCount = 0;

while ((files = DownloadFiles()) == null && retryCount < 3)
{
    retryCount++; 
    Console.WriteLine("Retrying {0} time", retryCount);
}
```

Comment: @PatrickHofman The code in the OP already works. The whole point of the question is to create a more readable/maintainable solution.  This solution is *dramatically worse* than the OP's in that regard.  That the code works doesn't mean it's a good answer.

Comment: @PatrickHofman So a code review that takes code and makes it worse is not a useful answer, it is in fact a not useful answer.  There is a specific button one can use to indicate that an answer is not useful.  It's the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
??? files; //type returned by the function
var retryCount = 0;

do 
{
    files = DownloadFiles();

    if (retryCount > 0)
        Console.WriteLine("Retrying {0} time", retryCount);       
} while (files == null && retryCount++ < 3)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code solution for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

a for loop may look neater:

```
var files = DownloadFiles();

for (int retryCount = 0; files == null && retryCount < 3; retryCount++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Retrying {0} time", retryCount);
    files = DownloadFiles();       
}
```

**edit**: additionally:
I normally hate "magic numbers" - constants without context, such as the 3 in the comparison, as it makes code less maintainable. This is particularly true if you want to give the user a choice of how many times to retry. I would normally use something like:

```
const maxRetries = 3;
```

and

```
retryCount < maxRetries
```

in the loop but thats up for debate.